# Calculate execution time for multiple functions in C++

Tags: c++

I have a function which in turn calls many functions. e.g.

```
void fun()
{
f1();
f2();
f3();
....
....
f50();
}
```

I want to calculate execution time of f1, f2....f50. Now if I calculate the time before and after execution of each function and then find the difference, I have to write it for all of these 50 functions which I want to avoid as it looks bad. Is there any simpler way to do this ?

Comment: Have you tried to use a profiler?

Answer (score 1):

Use a wrapper function which gets the actual function to call as an argument, and have the timing code only in that wrapper function.